# Change the default GRUB entry if I'm holding down a key?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've configured GRUB as such:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=2
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

So that it automatically boots Windows, unless I press ESC.

I was wondering if it was possible to add a script which, if a key (other than ESC) is pressed during boot, changess the default entry from "2" (Windows) to "0" (Ubuntu).